# Update TOC after merging 2 pdfs using itext

Tags: itext

Let me explain the scenario.

1) i have an existing pdf with TOC named A.pdf with 10 pages

2) i have two more pdf named B.pdf, C.pdf with TOC with 5 pages

3) Now i need to add B.pdf to A.pdf after 3rd page

4) and C.pdf to A.pdf after 7th page.

5) And need to update the TOC based on the Final sequence

Could any one have idea how to implement by using itext.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation, more specifically chapter 7 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book). You'll find an example named [ConcatenateBookmarks](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141) that does exactly what you're asking. That is: if by TOC, you are referring to bookmarks stored in an outline tree. In the example, we read all bookmarks using the `SimpleBookmark` class, we compose a new outline tree, shifting the bookmarks depending on the number of pages in each of the existing documents, and then we add the composed outline tree to the resulting PDF using the `setOutlines()` method.

If by TOC you mean, a sequence of pages showing a table of contents without any semantics or interactive features, you're asking something that is impossible due to the nature of PDF (which you'll discover once you start reading ISO-32000).